# Filter value second click show all element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This click button shows me only the elements based on the filter value. I was looking for a way in which the second click shows me all the elements again.

```js
$('.filter-button-group').on('click', 'a', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group filter-button-group">
  <a class="buttonFilterView" data-filter=".laboratori">
    <div class="buttonText">Laboratori</div>
    <div class="buttonIcon">
      <div class="buttonBackground buttonIconLaboratori">
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="grid-item customAllBlockViewHome isotopeWidthOne tuttidatogliere laboratori  pasticceria">
  ShowlaboratoriAndAll
</div>
<div class="grid-item customAllBlockViewHome isotopeWidthOne tuttidatogliere pasticceria">
  ShowOnlyAll prova
</div>
<div class="grid-item customAllBlockViewHome isotopeWidthOne tuttidatogliere pasticceria">
  ShowOnlyAll
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question

Comment: Firstly, where is the `button`? Secondly, where is the element with class `filter-button-group` regarding your click event handler?

Comment: Its already shows all element values

Comment: I expect on the first click that you only see ShowlaboratoriAndAll (and it already works), while on the second they return all visible (therefore also ShowOnlyAll)

Comment: you above comment confuses even more

Comment: The snippet does'nt seem to work. Getting `$grid is not defined` error. What is `$grid`? Are you using any plugin that you forgot to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to set an `active` class to the button when the grid is filtered so the next time I can know the state of the grid in order to decide how to filter it.

```
$('.filter-button-group').on('click', 'a', function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: '*'
    });
  } else {
    $grid.isotope({
      filter: $(this).attr('data-filter')
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

`'*'` allows you to display all the items.

A shorter syntax could be:

```
$('.filter-button-group').on('click', 'a', function() {
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: $(this).hasClass('active') ? '*' : $(this).attr('data-filter')
  });
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, the longest code is perfect too, thank you very much!